# Function not found from global namespace if there's an overload with different argument types

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++builder, c++builder-xe, name-lookup

If we have a function in the global namespace and an overload with different argument types in another namespace, it seems that C++Builder compiler doesn't find the function from the global namespace.

```
namespace A
{
    class a {
        friend void swap(a& first, a& second) { }
    };
}

class b {
    friend void swap(b& first, b& second) { }
};

namespace C
{
    class c {
        A::a dataA;
        b dataB;

        friend void swap(c& first, c& second)
        {
            swap(first.dataA, second.dataA); // no problem
            swap(first.dataB, second.dataB); // VC++12 compiles, C++Builder XE doesn't
        }

        friend void swap2(c& first, c& second) // no problem with a different name
        {
            swap(first.dataA, second.dataA);
            swap(first.dataB, second.dataB);
        }
    };
}
```

C++Builder gives the following errors:

```
E2357 Reference initialized with 'b', needs lvalue of type 'c'
E2342 Type mismatch in parameter 'first' (wanted 'c &', got 'b')
```

Visual C++ 2012 compiles this without errors.

I have understood that the function in global namespace should be found even when there exists a function with the same name and different argument types.

Have I missed something, or is this a bug in C++Builder?

Comment: Compiles with MinGW, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a compiler bug to me.  In both cases, ADL should
kick in.  In the first case, it looks in namespace `A`,
including names in namespace `A` that were only declared in
class `a`, and finds `A::swap`.  In the second case, it looks in
the global namespace (since that is where `b` is defined),
including names in the global namespace that were only declare
in class `b`, and finds `::swap`.

Of course, it starts with unqualified name lookup, which will
only find C::swap in both cases.  Apparently, C++Builder somehow
marks `::swap` as hidden in this case, and fails to consider it
in ADL.  In the case of ADL, however, both the global namespace
and namespace A should be treated equally.

The full rules are in §3.4.2.  It's pretty heavy going, but for
simple cases like yours, the implications are clear.

Comment: XE is several versions old. If this has not already been fixed in a later version, then it needs to be filed in QC so it can get fixed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't have access to any version of CodeBuilder, so I can't test.  It's up to the compiler's user community to verify this with the latest version, and send in a bug report if the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Members of local scope with same name as global always hide global one so Call it like,`A::a::swap(first.dataA, second.dataA);`.

Comment: There are no members with the same name in his code, however.